# Универсальный AsynkTask

Tags: java, android

**Имеется:**

Приложение которое взаимодействует с удаленной БД. В каждой активити(фрагменте) может запускаться по несколько `AsynkTask` на получение(запись) данных.

Получаются код такого вида в каждой активити(фрагменте):

```
public class AuthorizationActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    class GetServerTimeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        Connection conn;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try{
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+conServer+":"+conPort+"/"+conDB,
                        conUser,
                        conPass);

                ResultSet rs = null;
                CallableStatement cs = null;
                try{
                    cs = conn.prepareCall("{call skl_getdatetime()}");
                    rs = cs.executeQuery();
                    rs.next();
                    Date date = rs.getDate(1);
                    mCurrentDate = date.toString();
                }
                catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                finally{
                    try{
                        if (rs != null) rs.close();
                        if (cs != null) cs.close();
                    }
                    catch(java.sql.SQLException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                if (conn != null)
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            ..
        }
    }
    //
    class GetUserListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        //Аналогичного плана, получение списка пользователей
    }
```

**Мысли в слух:**

До поры до времени такое решение устраивало, но со временем как известно наступает период отвращения к коду и хочется сделать какой то универсальный механизм Task'ов.

По поводу прямого подключения к БД знаю, это очень и очень **плохо**, но это уже совсем другая история.

**Хотелось бы:**

Сделать какое то универсальное средство обращения к БД.

**Попытка:**

Вот такого плана есть задумка, но все равно есть такое ощущение что меняю "*шило на мыло*":

```
public class SQLServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, ServerAsyncTaskResult> {
    private static final String TAG = "SQLServerAsyncTask";

    public static final int REQUEST_SERVET_TIME = 0;
    ...

    public static interface OnServerResponse {
        public abstract void onServerResponse(String response, int requestType);
        public abstract void onServerResponseMessage(String message, int requestType);
    }

    private static OnServerResponse getOnServerResponse(final Context context) {
        if (context == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (context instanceof OnServerResponse) {
            return (OnServerResponse) context;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Context context;


    public SQLServerAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected ServerAsyncTaskResult doInBackground(Integer... requests) {
        Response response = null;
        Exception exception = null;
        Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+conServer+":"+conPort+"/"+conDB,
                    conUser,
                    conPass);
        requestType = requests[0];
        try {
            switch (requests[0]) {

                case REQUEST_REGISTER: {
                    ...
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        ...
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ServerAsyncTaskResult result) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Так вот, хотелось бы услышать Ваше авторитетное мнение по поводу решения данной проблемы, может быть сталкивался кто нить с аналогичной задачей, и наработал хорошее решение.

Буду рад любому ответу и конструктивной критике. Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Сейчас все большую популярность набирает библиотека RxJava и не просто так. Почитайте про нее и про ее дополнение - RxAndroid. Действительно крутая штука и забудь об AsyncTask'ах

Comment: @Rishka да, читал как то на хабре, но не особо уверен что они приемлема именно в случае общения с базой, как мне показалось она более заточена на `REST API` хотя могу и ошибаться...

Comment: Если есть возможность организовать универсальный протокол (запрос-ответ), то достаточно сделать одну таску (например, в базовом классе активити или еще где-то), и уже в нее передавать параметры запроса, а она уже будет возвращать универсальный ответ с данными, откуда можно получить специфические данные по конкретному запросу. У меня в приложении так сделано, но сейчас слишком долго вычленять код работающего примера.

Comment: @droid она отлично подходит для всего:) В своем приложении и подписываюсь на изменения в базе и обновляю список, если что-то новое добавлено (например). Просто это нужно разобраться, потратить время и научиться

Comment: @RuslanA `а она уже будет возвращать универсальный ответ` да вот с этим тоже ситуация интересная, так как может возвращаться набор, одно значение или вообще ничего%)

Comment: У меня есть базовый класс ответа, внутри которого лежат специфические данные. Зная, какой тип запроса я послал, я знаю, к какому типу ответа преобразовать то, что вернул сервер.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону завернуть в ContentProvider и загрузку данных через CursorLoader'ы.

Comment: @lsillarionov ну для того что бы что то получать из локально БД (насколько я понял связку `ContentProvider`  и `CursorLoader`) нужно в эту базу как то эти данные загрузить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую предложить свое виденье решения данного вопроса.

Использовать будем связку `IntentService` и `BroadcastReceiver`.

Создадим свой сервис, который будет взаимодействовать с `БД`:

```
public class DBConnectionService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "DBConnectionService";

    public static final String RESPONSE_CODE = "ResponseCode";
    public static final String RESPONSE_DATA = "ResponseData";

    public static final String REQUEST_TYPE = "RequestType";

    public static final int RESPONSE_OK = 1;
    public static final int RESPONSE_ERROR = -1;

    public static final int REQUEST_SERVET_TIME = 0;

    ...

    Connection conn;

    private boolean isDBConnect(){
        try {
            if(conn == null){
                conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+conServer+":"+conPort+"/"+conDB,
                        conUser,
                        conPass);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void sendResponseOk(String action, int requestType, Serializable data){
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.setAction(action);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.putExtra(RESPONSE_CODE, RESPONSE_OK);
        intent.putExtra(REQUEST_TYPE, requestType);
        intent.putExtra(RESPONSE_DATA, data);

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    private void sendResponseError(String action, int requestType, Serializable data){
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.setAction(action);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.putExtra(RESPONSE_CODE, RESPONSE_ERROR);
        intent.putExtra(REQUEST_TYPE, requestType);
        intent.putExtra(RESPONSE_DATA, data);

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        int requestType = intent.getIntExtra(REQUEST_TYPE, -1);

        Serializable data;
        if(!isDBConnect()){
            sendResponseError(action, requestType, null);
            return;
        }

        try {
            switch (requestType) {

                case REQUEST_SERVET_TIME: {
                    ...
                    data = ...
                }
                ...
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            data = e.getCause();
            sendResponseError(action, requestType, data);
            return;
        }
        sendResponseOk(action, requestType, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            if(conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вызываем сервис в активити так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DBConnectionService.class);
intent.setAction(getClass().getName());
intent.putExtra(DBConnectionService.REQUEST_TYPE, DBConnectionService.REQUEST_SERVET_TIME);
startService(intent);
```

Теперь остается дело за малым, поймать ответ, для этих целей в активити создадим внутренний класс - BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class ResponseBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int responseCode = intent.getIntExtra(DBConnectionService.RESPONSE_CODE, 0);
        int requestType = intent.getIntExtra(DBConnectionService.REQUEST_TYPE,  0);

        if(code == DBConnectionService.RESPONSE_OK){
            switch(type){
                case DBConnectionService.REQUEST_SERVET_TIME: {
                    serverDateReceived();
                }
            }
        } else {
            //we have an error
        }
    }
}
```

Регистрируем слушатель при создании активити, а так же не забываем его убирать при уничтожении:

```
private ResponseBroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            getClass().getName());
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    mBroadcastReceiver = new ResponseBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

Так же как вариант можно создать какую нибудь базовую активити, в которой все это будет реализовано и наследоваться уже от нее.

> Код написан на колене и не претендует на звание стопроцентно правильного и оптимального...пробуйте, экспериментируйте.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! наверн этим путем и пойду.

Answer (score 3):

Вы когда нибудь слышали про разделение логики, какой нибудь MVC? Разделить код на 3 основные компоненты (данные, логику и отображение) чтобы модификация одного из них оказывала минимальное воздействие на остальные.

У вас в первой версии например вот эти строки кода вообще не к месту:

```
                Date date = rs.getDate(1);
                mCurrentDate = date.toString();
```

По хорошему вам нужно создать класс - поставщик данных (например назовем его DatabaseHelper), а всякие Activity вообще не должны знать откуда берутся данные - по jdbc, из JSON или из локальной базы.

Т.е. весь ваш код свернется таким образом:

```
public class AuthorizationActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    class GetServerTimeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Date date = DatabaseHelper.getDate();
            mCurrentDate = date.toString();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            ..
        }
    }
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ! `Вы когда нибудь слышали про разделение логики, какой нибудь MVC?` - да конечно слышал, но так же и встречал мнения о том что в андроиде Activity является и View и Controller

Comment: но такой подход избавит лишь "раздутости" Task'ов, при этом их количество в каждой Activity останется прежним